# Python unittest, skip tests when using a base-test-class

Tags: python, python-unittest

Whilst testing one of our web-apps for clarity I have created a `BaseTestClass` which inherits `unittest.TestCase`. The `BaseTestClass` includes my `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods, which each of my `<Page>Test` classes then inherit from.

Due to different devices under test having similar pages with some differences I wanted to use the `@unittest.skipIf()` decorator but its proving difficult. Instead of 'inheriting' the decorator from `BaseTestClass`, if I try to use that decorator Eclipse tries to auto-import `unittest.TestCase` into `<Page>Test`, which doesn't seem right to me.

Is there a way to use the `skip` decorators when using a `Base`?

```
class BaseTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp():
        #do setup stuff
        device = "Type that blocks"

    def tearDown():
        #clean up
```

One of the test classes in a separate module:

```
class ConfigPageTest(BaseTestClass):

    def test_one(self):
        #do test

    def test_two(self):
        #do test

    @unittest.skipIf(condition, reason) <<<What I want to include
    def test_three(self):
        #do test IF not of the device type that blocks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously this requires unittest2 (or Python 3, I assume), but other than that, your example was pretty close. Make sure the name of your real test code gets discovered by your unit test discovery mechanism (`test_*.py` for nose).

```
#base.py
import sys
import unittest2 as unittest

class BaseTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        device = "Type that blocks"
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

And in the actual code:

```
# test_configpage.py
from base import *

class ConfigPageTest(BaseTestClass):

    def test_one(self):
        pass

    def test_two(self):
        pass

    @unittest.skipIf(True, 'msg')
    def test_three(self):
        pass
```

Which gives the output

```
.S.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.016s

OK (SKIP=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd never thought to use the wild-card import.